# Moving Visual Studio 2012 JavaScript Intellisense Markup to Separate File

Tags: javascript, intellisense, visual-studio-2012

I love the intellisense feature of Visual Studio, including the ability to generate my own XML markup for the methods I create.  However, sometimes the comments actually get in the way of seeing what I'm doing (especially when the method is a few lines long and the intellisense for it is three or four times longer than the code itself!)

Under Visual Studio 2012, it should be possible to [move the intellisense markup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874692.aspx) to a separate file, adding `.intellisense.js` to the end of the file name and placing the files in the same directory.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work.

As an example, suppose the file `module.js` contains the following code:

```
var module = (function (my) {
    /// <summary>Description of the module</summary>

    my.action = function(doThis) {
        /// <summary>Take an action</summary>
        /// <param type="String">Do this action</param>
        /// <returns type="String" />
        return doThis.toLowerCase();
    }

    return my;
}(module || {}));
```

I've tried creating a file in the same directory called `module.intellisense.js` and moving the XML comments from `module.js` into here:

```
intellisense.annotate(module, {
    'action': function() {
        /// <summary>Take an action</summary>
        /// <param type="String">Do this action</param>
        /// <returns type="String" />
    }
});

intellisense.annotate(window, {
    'module': function() {
        /// <summary>Description of the module</summary>
    }
});
```

After saving the files, I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to force the intellisense to update, then give it a moment to think.  Afterward, when I type `module.action(`, I get no intellisense assistance.  **What needs to be done to make functional, custom external-file JavaScript intellisense in Visual Studio 2012?**

Comment: Are you testing this in building a Windows Store app, or a web site project? Also, it looks like you have an extra closing paren at the end of the module definition: (module || {}));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have an extra closing parenthesis in your example of module.js, so it can be a problem.
2. As I understand, module.intellisense.js is not apply to module.js itself. But other files, that will use module.js works fine.
3. Changes in module.intellisense.js are not apply immediately, even if use Ctrl+Shift+J - need some time or an actions with file.

Comment: Great answer!  The first point was moot; the extra parenthesis was a typo when writing the question.  However, your second point was critical...I was trying to get the intellisense to work within `module.js`.  Once I went to a different file, the intellisense was working.

Comment: As I realised, IntelliSense updates automaticaly. Ctrl+Shift+J no makes sence if you use local files only, this hot keys updates remote files (scripts inluded via http://).